# How Do I add A video into Light box?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im new to all of this and im definitely trying to get better! The video i am trying to add into this light box is my new commercial: (http://www.gatorgraphix.com/uploads/5/1/7/6/5176322/gator_graphix_commercial.mp4) 
but im having trouble getting it inside my light box and to play automatically. Can you help?? Here is my script :

```
<htmL>
    <head>
        <title>Gator Graphix™ Commercial</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

        body
        {
             font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
        }

        .backdrop
    {
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background:#000;
            opacity: .0;
            filter:alpha(opacity=0);
            z-index:50;
            display:none;
        }


        .box
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:20%;
            left:30%;
            width:640px;
            height:310px;
            background:#ffffff;
            z-index:51;
            padding:10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
            box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
            display:none;

        }

        .close
        {
            float:right;
            margin-right:6px;
            cursor:pointer;
        }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.lightbox').click(function(){
                     $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
                     $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
                     $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');

                });

                $('.close').click(function(){
                    close_box();

                });

                $('.backdrop').click(function(){
                    close_box();

                });

            });


            function close_box()
            {
                $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
                        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
                    });
            }

        </script>

    <Head>
    <body>

    <h1>Gator Graphix™ Commercial</h1>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox">Click To View Our New Commercial</a>

    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="close">x</div>Gator Graphix™ Commercial</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://iaian7.com/webcode/mediaboxAdvanced

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with a few lightbox scripts, I've found shadowbox - ( http://www.shadowbox-js.com/download.html ) to be pretty flawless..

On the download page linked here you can select all of the player types and this will allow you to embed flash, videos, images and more.